# Changing text in webpage with no reload?

Tags: jquery

i do not have any code experience in this but i would like to know how to have my text that is in my div, "content here" change text, every 10 seconds or so..

```
<div class="module">
        <div class="module-header">Quotes</div>
        <div class="module-content">
            <div class="m_recentThreads">
             Content here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the text supposed to change to?

Comment: Yes i have tried but with failure, the text i want to display is quotes from users... @urbz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for you..

`setInterval()` and `toggleClass()` is the key here:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E4xqg/149/)**